# Streaky artefacts, subsurf, how to avoid?

Tags: subdivision-surface

How do I avoid strange streaky artifacts like these on the concave part of the object?

Tried to remove doubles and beveling with no effect

[image]

[image]

Comment: "*How do I avoid strange streaky artifacts?*" Use [proper topology](http://topologyguides.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using n-gons (polygons with more than 4 vertices) those will not subdivide nicely..

[image]

Get rid of it (and the one on the other side of the object)

Add one more loop cut (so that you have an even number of vertices in the edge loop)

Select the edge ring, use **Grid fill** and set the span to something that makes sense.

Grid fill will create proper topology based on quads.

Repeat grid fill on the other side of the object.

[image]

Comment: Wow! That's It! Thanks for this thorough explanation. 
Kindly and with much appreciation, Mikael